# Package in hirsute-updates depends on package in hirsute-proposed

Tags: nvidia, package-management, updates, dependencies

EDIT: I'm running Ubuntu 21.04 hirsute.

Since this morning, apt shows `linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04` to be upgradable on my machine, but fails to actually install the update. Unfortunately, `nvidia-smi` also stopped working, so I suspect this might be related.

EDIT: Here's the output of `sudo apt update`:

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Get:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease [115 kB]
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease             
Get:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Fetched 216 kB in 0s (652 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.

$ apt list --upgradable -a
Listing... Done
linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04/hirsute-updates,hirsute-security 5.11.0-34.36 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.11.0-31.33]
linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04/now 5.11.0-31.33 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.11.0-34.36]
```

Here's what I get when trying to force the update:

```
$ sudo apt install --only-upgrade linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04 : Depends: linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.11.0-34-generic (= 5.11.0-34.36) but it is not going to be installed
                                              Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-470 (>= 470.63.01) but 470.57.02-0ubuntu0.21.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So the problem seems to be that `nvidia-kernel-common-470` version 470.63.01 hasn't made it to hirsute-updates yet.

EDIT: `apt-cache policy` gives me:

```
$ apt-cache policy linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04
linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04:
  Installed: 5.11.0-31.33
  Candidate: 5.11.0-34.36
  Version table:
     5.11.0-34.36 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/restricted amd64 Packages
 *** 5.11.0-31.33 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ apt-cache policy nvidia-kernel-common-470
nvidia-kernel-common-470:
  Installed: 470.57.02-0ubuntu0.21.04.1
  Candidate: 470.57.02-0ubuntu0.21.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 470.57.02-0ubuntu0.21.04.1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/restricted amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

What's the safest way to proceed here? Should I wait for nvidia-kernel-common-470 to be bumped on hirsute-updates?

Comment: @guiverc thanks for commenting, I added the information you requested! Please do let me know if I'm still missing something.

Comment: Why the `--only-upgrade` switch? Does it work without?

Comment: @vanadium I guess I just wanted to avoid installing something unnecessary, since I've been running the vanilla installation (as far as I know). Removing `--only-upgrade` gives the exact same result unfortunately.

Comment: It might be a (temporary?) inconsistency in your software mirror. You may want to temporarily switch to the main servers.

Comment: @vanadium Right, that makes sense. The situation seems to be the same on https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/nvidia-kernel-common-470 and https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute-updates/nvidia-kernel-common-470, however. Are they using the main servers there? Anyway, I guess I'll just wait for the update to trickle down. Thanks a lot for replying!

Comment: You can (temporarily if you wish) switch servers in "Software and Updates", "Ubuntu Software tab". Then close the tool, and try the command again. If it works, you know it was your server. If it does not work, then just switch back to your own server and indeed wait a bit.